# uninitialized constant EKEventEditViewController (NameError) when using rubymotion

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I keep getting the error: uninitialized constant EKEventEditViewController (NameError) when trying to initialize the controller.

```
            controller = EKEventEditViewController.alloc.init
```

Do I need to require any particular framework to use this controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`EKEventEditViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventEditViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) is declared in [`EventKitUI`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EventKitUIFrameworkRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009663) framework.

So, you need to include that framework in your `Rakefile`:

```
app.frameworks << 'EventKitUI'
```